# How can I create new agents in a function in the agent Class that have certain parameter values?

Tags: anylogic

I have created a function in the Palette agent class that assigns certain values to the parameters p_quantity, p_articleID and p_customerID.

If p_quantity > 600, I want a 2nd agent to be created with the same parameters of this agent. Only that the 2nd agent has the remaining quantity as parameter value.

For example, if p_quantity = 900, then there should be 2 agents with the same customer ID and item ID. But one agent has the quantity 600, the other the remaining 300.

My consideration was a for loop in the function that is called in the "on startup" field of the agent class. However, I cannot access the agent population here. Could someone help me with this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LepMn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your agent population sits 1 level higher in the hierarchy, i.e. `main.add_Pallete(...)` should work.

Learn about your model hierarchy and how to navigate it here: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to